# Typescript says the type is not assignable

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble understanding what is going on here. Typescript is reporting that two string variables are not assignable. I think this has something to do with the `Object.freeze`, as removing it allows the assignment to occur. Any help is appreciated.

```
const SomeEnum = Object.freeze({
  VAL_1: 'VAL_1',
  VAL_2: 'VAL_2'
});

console.log(typeof(SomeEnum.VAL_1)); //String

let temp = SomeEnum.VAL_1;
let temp2 = SomeEnum.VAL_2;

console.log(typeof(temp) == typeof(temp2)) //true

temp = temp2; //Typescript says the type is not assignable
```

Is the readonly transitive on new variables? How might one change the values of a variable when the inferred type is a member variable of this object? I inherited code that eschewed `enums` for `Object.freeze`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.freeze()` returns your object as [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) and can therefore infer the literal string types of `VAL_1` and `VAL_2`. If you take a look at the types of your `temp` and `temp2` variables you'll notice that both of them have literal string types as well and you cannot assign `"VAL_2"` to type `"VAL_1"`.

If you remove the `Object.freeze()` TypeScript will infer the properties of `SomeEnum` as arbitrary `string`s. And `string` is assignable to type `string`.

Also note that [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) only returns the JavaScript types (in your case `"string"`) and never the TypeScript types as they [don't exist at runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure).

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operand is a JavaScript construct. While there is a link to the types that the TypeScript compiler infers, they should not be used interchangeably.

In your example, both properties have a JS type of `String`, however in TypeScript the property types are `VAL_1` and `VAL_2` respectively. The use of `Object.freeze` tells the TypeScript compiler these properties cannot change and hence instead of inferring `string` types for them, the compiler instead will assign them [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) types.

Answer (score 1):

**This is because of default behavior of Object.freez()**

The Object.freeze() method is used to freeze an object. Freezing an object does not allow new properties to be added to the object and prevents removing or altering the existing properties. Object.freeze() preserves the enumerability, configurability, writability, and prototype of the object. It returns the passed object and does not create a frozen copy.

Reference [Check](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-object-freeze-method/)

If you still want to achieve than you need to define type for each key as below

```
const SomeEnum = Object.freeze({
    KEY_1: "VAL_1",
    KEY_2: "VAL_2",
});

let temp: (typeof SomeEnum)[keyof typeof SomeEnum] = SomeEnum.KEY_1;
let temp2: (typeof SomeEnum)[keyof typeof SomeEnum] = SomeEnum.KEY_2;

console.log(typeof temp == typeof temp2); //true

temp = temp2;
console.log(temp);
```

Here, `typeof SomeEnum[keyof typeof SomeEnum]` is used to represent the union of all the values in the `SomeEnum` object. By specifying this type for `temp` and `temp2`, TypeScript will recognize that both variables can be assigned to each other.